# How to aggregate rows in the range of timestamp in vertica db (vsql)

Tags: sql, vertica, vsql

Suppose I have a table with data like this:

```
         ts          | bandwidth_bytes
---------------------+-----------------
 2021-08-27 22:00:00 |    3792
 2021-08-27 21:45:00 |    1164
 2021-08-27 21:30:00 |    7062
 2021-08-27 21:15:00 |    3637
 2021-08-27 21:00:00 |    2472
 2021-08-27 20:45:00 |    1328
 2021-08-27 20:30:00 |    1932
 2021-08-27 20:15:00 |    1434
 2021-08-27 20:00:00 |    1530
 2021-08-27 19:45:00 |    1457
 2021-08-27 19:30:00 |    1948
 2021-08-27 19:15:00 |    1160
```

I need to output something like this:

```
         ts          | bandwidth_bytes
---------------------+-----------------
 2021-08-27 22:00:00 |    15,655
 2021-08-27 21:00:00 |    7166
 2021-08-27 20:00:00 |    6095
```

I want to do sum `bandwidth_bytes` over 1 hour timestamp of data.
I want to do this in vsql specifically.

More columns are present but for simplification I have shown only these two.

Comment: Have you tried rounding your timestamp to the hour?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date_trunc()`:

```
select [date_trunc('hour', ts)][1] as ts_hh, sum(bandwidth_bytes)
from t
group by ts_hh;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Vertica's lovely function `TIME_SLICE()`.

You can't only go by hour, you can also go by slices of 2 or 3 hours, which `DATE_TRUNC()` does not offer.

You seem to want all between `20:00:01` and `21:00:00` to belong to a time slice of `21:00:00`. In both `DATE_TRUNC()` and `TIME_SLICE()`, however, it's `20:00:00` to `20:59:59` that belongs to the same time slice. So I subtracted one second before applying `TIME_SLICE()` .

```
WITH
-- your in data ...
indata(ts,bandwidth_bytes) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 22:00:00',3792
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 21:45:00',1164
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 21:30:00',7062
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 21:15:00',3637
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 21:00:00',2472
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 20:45:00',1328
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 20:30:00',1932
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 20:15:00',1434
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 20:00:00',1530
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 19:45:00',1457
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 19:30:00',1948
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-27 19:15:00',1160
)
SELECT
  TIME_SLICE(ts - INTERVAL '1 SECOND' ,1,'HOUR','END') AS ts
, SUM(bandwidth_bytes)    AS bandwidth_bytes
FROM indata
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
         ts          | bandwidth_bytes 
---------------------+-----------------
 2021-08-27 22:00:00 |           15655
 2021-08-27 21:00:00 |            7166
 2021-08-27 20:00:00 |            6095
```